# is there any way to know the oracle database instance failure count

Tags: oracle, instance, database-administration

I am working on Oracle database, I have to know about instance failure, also I need to save instance failure count in a file, if there is any command to do this? where can I get the information of the instance failure ? any logs ?

I am new to Oracle, I don't know about what are the commands used to get instance failure.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get the instance count in oracle,

```
SELECT COUNT(STATUS) INSTANCES_RUNNING,
       sys_context('USERENV', 'INSTANCE_NAME') "I'm logged in" 
FROM  GV$INSTANCE
WHERE STATUS='OPEN'
GROUP BY STATUS
```

Oracle contains a set of underlying views that are maintained by the database server. These views are called dynamic performance views.

The dynamic performance views are `V$` Views and `GV$` Views.

In oracle RAC I think the following query helps,

```
select *  from v$active_instances
```